# Memory addressing and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory

whenever a pointer variable is incremented by one, it will point to the next integer’s location (four bytes ahead in this case) as an int variable data  spanning through four bytes.

---

how can i access each byte address and print the value stored in it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   int array[2] = {20,30};
   int *iptr ;
   iptr = array ;
   printf("Address of data = %p\n", &array[0]);
   printf("Address of data = %p\n", &array[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i access each byte address and print the value stored in it ?

For example the following way

```
unsigned char *p = ( unsigned char * )array;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( array ); i++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", p[i] ); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `char*` or `unsigned char*`, incrementing the pointer will point to the very next byte.

Answer (score 2):

try changing `int *iptr` to `char *iptr` and then print it `printf("%d", iptr[0]);`